# How to get the correct display mode refresh rate as a float in Java?

Tags: java

The following example prints 59 on my system, because the return type of `getRefreshRate` is `int`.

```java
import java.awt.*;

class Fps {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.
      getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice[] devices = env.getScreenDevices();
    for (int i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
      DisplayMode mode = devices[i].getDisplayMode();
      int depth = mode.getBitDepth();
      int rate = mode.getRefreshRate();
      System.out.println ("depth: " + depth + " rate: " + rate);
    }
  }
}
```

But this is incorrect, because the real refresh rate is 59.951. This seems to be usual nowadays on [Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/screen-refresh-rate-in-windows-does-not-apply-the-user-selected-settings-on-monitors-tvs-that-report-specific-tv-compatible-timings-0a7a6a38-6c6a-2aec-debc-5183a76b9e1d#:%7E:text=The%2059Hz%20setting%20makes%20sure,a%20value%20of%2059.94Hz).

How to get the correct value in Java or at least a correctly rounded value?

Comment: If I'm reading the linked article right, then it sounds like you can check if the returned rate is 59 and if so interpret it to be 59.94 instead. Does this behave correctly for your use cases?

Comment: My Windows reports 59.951.